# How to add more background on the left and the right of the navbar?

Tags: html, css, background, navigation, navbar

I wanted the navbar to be shown on the left and right ends of the page, but I wanted the text to stay in the center of the page.

I also tried with padding but it didn't work. And I tried to make the left and right border bigger, but that didn't work too. (What more do you need Stack Overflow?)

HTML code:

```
 <div id="div1">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">All Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Quick and easy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Breakfast</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Lunch</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Dinner</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Desserts</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="lo">Must try</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Healthy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
    margin-left: 15%;
}
#div1{
    margin-left: -15%;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 197, 6);
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(190, 188, 188);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(190, 188, 188);
    margin-left: 18%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(254, 156, 0);
}
nav li{
    float: left;
```

Comment: You should use flexbox, floats are outdated.

Comment: You also, specifically just want the navbar to stretch from the left to the rightside of the screen, and place the links in the middle?

Comment: Yes, I want the links to be in the middle, and the right and left side to be just background.

Answer (score 0):

This is a navbar that fills the screen and a specified height, it centers the text as well, it just an example for what yours should look like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        * {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
    
        .navbar {
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
        }
    
        .navbar ul {
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
          justify-content:center;
          border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;
        }
    
        .navbar ul li {
          list-style-type:none;
          margin:20px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Help</li>
          <li>Recipes</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```